# Reactive power fluctuation

Tags: alternator, power-grid, reactive-power, gas

We have 6 Caterpillar gas generators 3520c.
One of them when synches with the grid. Its kVAR fluctuates over wide range and the aux voltage too and the excitation volt and current. We checked AVR and easy gen (it's for control).
What we can check again?
Taking into consideration, active power is stable.

Comment: When the generator fluctuates, its frequency is still in sync to the grid? What about the phase shift, is it stable or does it fluctuate too?

Comment: You added the tag `avr` but that is to denote AVR microcontroller architecture. Please expand what you mean by "AVR."

Comment: @uwe The frequency is stable

Comment: AVR is automatic voltage regulator

Comment: What did Caterpillar say when you called them for support?

Comment: We didn't call them yet
@relayman357